# Strange DIV redimension on Chrome

Tags: php, html, css, google-chrome, web

I'm working on a new php website and something strange just started happening... I have a file for my top navbar so i can include it on every page and it's working great, except for one detail.. I was creating a register form and realize sometimes when i refresh the website on Chrome with F5 multiple times the top navbar where it says "Iniciar sesión o registrar" appears in 2 lines, if you keep refreshing eventually will switch from 2 lines view to 1 line view which doesn't make any sense since you're only refreshing and nothing else.. If you refresh with Shift+F5 80% of the time appears on 1 line, but still goes on 2 lines sometimes..

Another thing i realize is that it only happens when there's a FORM tag, so if you're for example on the main website it won't happen since there're no forms there.. You can keep refreshing with F5 or Shift+F5 the main website and it will always appear on 1 line (like it should)..

For me it doesn't make any sense since it's loading the same file, why would it show different almost everytime when you refresh?

This is the main website: *Link offline*

And this is where the error happens: *Link offline*

By the way, this only happens on Chrome.

Thank you

EDIT: I'm working on Chrome Versión 38.0.2125.111 dev-m (64-bit) with Windows 7
I know it's not only me because some friends got the error too

EDIT 2: I updated chrome to the lastest version and it's still happening

EDIT 3: I did file a bug.. Here's the ID: 455535

EDIT 4: Solved by changing float left on class login with display inline block, still don't know what was happening.. Links offline now

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  What version of Chrome do you have, and what OS + version are you using?

Comment: I see it. It's because `width: 405px` is commented out in `style-navbar.css`.

Comment: The error looks like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Sxdlm.jpg

Comment: Nope, that's not the reason... I tried setting the width manually so it wont go on 2 lines but still it appears a small white space on top of the navbar, even tho it doesn't go on 2 lines it's still happening

Comment: OK.  I'm using Chrome 41 on Linux.  Before you file a chrome bug, update your chrome version.  Before you do file a Chrome bug, make sure you update to the latest.  I just tested on Chrome 40 (not up-to-date) and Windows 7 x64, and can reproduce.

Comment: @Jonathan I'm using Chrome 40 on OS X and it says it's up-to-date. Are you using the development track?

Comment: Actually I compiled it myself - so it's technically chromium, not Chrome.

Comment: I can confirm that the issue is presenet on Windows 7 x86 40.0.2214.94 m (up-to-date).

Comment: I just update my Chrome to the lastest version and it's still happening.. One thing i realize in this version is that on the main website it appears the small white space on top of the navbar, which it doesn't happened before..

Comment: White space on the main website it's only happening on my local version (WHICH IS OBVIOUSLY THE SAME IT'S ON THE WEBSITE) .. I looked at the source code on Chrome and Firefox and i found out this (on the main website, the register one stays the same).. http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img905/2665/acu0ro.jpg ... On chrome it shows the HEAD inside the BODY, which is the WRONG way..

Comment: When it is displaying wrong for me, the head is not inside of the body.  Have you tried adding a doctype?  For HTML5: <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: I added it and still the same.. But, i manage to solve the white space on the main website by changing the encoding of the file... Did the same for the register one but still the 2 lines thing..

Comment: I'm going to go with Timmerz and say, file a bug: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list   Post back with the bug ID here.

Comment: Here's the bug ID: 455535

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing this is a bug in Chrome.  As suggested in the comments, I'd file a bug.  I suspect it has something to do with the left float within the left float, but could be totally wrong.

To get it working on your site, try replacing the .navbar .tools .login class in style-navbar.css this:

```
.navbar .tools .login {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px; 
}
```

Comment: This actually solved my problem LOL... Changed float: left with display: inline-block; and it's now displaying correct. Thank you!